# Open my app from a link

Tags: android, android-intent, android-filter, android-implicit-intent

In my app the server send this link: `appname://veryfy?email=test@mail.com&token=asdf-asdf-asdf-xcfghfgh` but is it possible to get the values like `email= test@mail.com` and the `token = sdfdkgdkgjgfd`.

So far I've only added this intent filter inside my manifest but the app is not called:

```
<intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>

                <data android:mimeType="text/plain" android:scheme="appname://"/>
            </intent-filter>
```

Note this should open my app when the link is clicked in the browser

Comment: Take care of the spelling: apname vs. appname

Comment: @Henry done, thanks for the note

Comment: @DarkoPetkovski i have edited my answer with the url you are getting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the email and token by getting the Activity's intent like this:

```
    <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/>
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>

                    <data android:mimeType="text/plain" android:scheme="https" 
                     android:host="api.myapp.com"
                     android:pathPrefix="/api/v2/verify"/>
       </intent-filter>
```

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
Uri data = intent.getData();
String email = data.getQueryParameter("email");
String token = data.getQueryParameter("token");
```

Answer (score 0):

The scheme in your filter should just be appname, not appname://

```
android:scheme="appname"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain" android:scheme="appname"/>
</intent-filter>
```

and the link on the web:

```
<a href="appname://veryfy?email=test@mail.com&token=asdf-asdf-asdf-xcfghfgh">
```

Getting data in your Activity:

```
// check if this intent is started via custom scheme link
Intent intent = getIntent();
String action = intent.getAction();
if (action != null && action.equals(Intent.ACTION_VIEW) {
   Uri uri = intent.getData();
   String scheme = uri.getScheme();
   if (scheme.equals("appname") {
      String email = uri.getQueryParameter("email");
      String token = uri.getQueryParameter("token");
   }
}
```

Comment: and do you have any idea how can i get the email and the token?

Comment: Actually i've just noticed that this is not the link that im getting, can I parse this one: https://api.myapp.com/api/v2/verify?email=test@gmail.com&token=1231-0444-44e0-b‌​b69-4192fd0fec6b

Comment: Ok, then change your scheme with "https". For that there is no conflict if you want to use that scheme to other things, you can verify that the host is the of the web. `if(uri.getHost() .equals("api.myapp.com") ...`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    <activity
          android:name=".MainActivity"
          android:label="@string/title_activity_main" 
          android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
                        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/>
                        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>

                        <data android:mimeType="text/plain" android:scheme="appname"/>
           </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

To get your url parameter write this in your activity

```
Uri data = getIntent().getData();
String scheme = data.getScheme(); 
String host = data.getHost(); 
List<String> params = data.getPathSegments();
String first = params.get(0); 
String second = params.get(1);
```

Comment: Actually i've just noticed that this is not the link that im getting, can I parse this one:
`https://api.myapp.com/api/v2/verify?email=test@gmail.com&token=1231-0444-44e0-bb69-4192fd0fec6b`