# How to create a deep link in app?

Tags: android, deeplink

I am working in app. There need to create a deep link. User can able to share particular item and user can open direct page from click link. I follow [enter link description here](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/app-indexing/deep-linking.html)

```
 <intent-filter >
          <!--  android:autoVerify="true"-->

       <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
       <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
       <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data android:scheme="https"
                android:host="www.jobzminer.com"
                android:pathPrefix="/appplay" />

            <data android:scheme="jobzminer"
                android:host="appplay" />
   </intent-filter>
```

but when i put link into browser then its not working.

Comment: What is the link, that you are clicking in the browser?

Comment: Thanks for replying @Eric . i have the url like this : jobzminer://appplay

Comment: Change your url to: `https://www.jobzminer.com/appplay` and it will work.

Comment: Its redirect into web.need to set up any things in web?@Eric

Comment: I think it should work. Try clearing your browser as a default app, if it helps.

Comment: Hi @Eric ,if i need to pass any parameter , How to do this?Thanks for your contribution . its work . i was testing wrong way.

Comment: You have 2 up-vote . can you help how to pass parameter through uri?@Eric

Comment: I seen that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32761923/open-my-app-from-a-link/32762205#32762205. but i want know that how to add email and token with uri? can you give a example..

Comment: See my answer. I have updated it.

Comment: Thanks @Eric for your more contribution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, to update your url to: `https://www.jobzminer.com/appplay`. Also clear your browser as a default app.

To pass parameters, you could use query parameters. Change your url like this: `https://www.jobzminer.com/appplay?param1=hello&param2=world`

Then in your activity. Do this:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
Uri data = intent.getData();
String param1 = data.getQueryParameter("param1");
String param2 = data.getQueryParameter("param2");
```

You can also see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32762205/2367703).

Answer (score 0):

Deeplinking can be well achieved by Branch SDK. They have amazing docs to integrate branch sdk and get going. Refer this link https://dev.branch.io/getting-started/sdk-integration-guide/guide/android/