# Can i pass data using Deep linking between two apps in android

Tags: java, android, deep-linking

I am working in an Android application where i need to **share data between two applications.**

I achieved the same using
**Content Provider, Shared Preferences, Intents** .

But is there a way to execute the same using **Deep linking** in Android?

What i am trying to ask is, upon button click in app 1, app 2 needs to be opened.

The code which i use for deeplinking is

```
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="myapp" />
        </intent-filter>
```

in manifest and we will get the intent in Activity.

Can anyone please guide me regarding this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42511715/passing-data-between-two-android-apps-using-intent

Comment: Hi dude @Hemant Parmar, I have clearly mentioned in my question that i achieved passing data using intents. What i need to know is whether i can pass the data using Deep linking in Android

Comment: Both of the apps made by you.?

Comment: Yes dude @Sreyas

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the [Uri](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html) associated with the `Intent` using

```
Uri uri = getIntent().getData();
```

you can then using one of the getter available to retrieve your `id`, if you provide one. E.g. `myapp://wallet/test?id=100`

```
String id = data.getQueryParameter("id");
```

should give you `100`

Comment: please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36280007/how-to-create-a-deep-link-in-app

Comment: Upon loading a url in a webview in App 1, App 2 needs to be opened. This is my requirement dude